# Regex - Matching text AFTER certain characters

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to scrape data from some text and dump it into an array. Consider the following text as example data:

```
| Example Data
| Title: This is a sample title
| Content: This is sample content
| Date: 12/21/2012
```

I am currently using the following regex to scrape the data that is specified after the 'colon' character:

```
/((?=:).+)/
```

Unfortunately this regex also grabs the colon and the space after the colon. How do I only grab the data?

Also, I'm not sure if I'm doing this right.. but it appears as though the outside parens causes a match to return an array. Is this the function of the parens?

EDIT: I'm using Rubular to test out my regex expressions

Comment: Also, `/:\K.+/` or `/:\s*\K.+/`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could change it to:

```
/: (.+)/
```

and grab the contents of group 1. A lookbehind works too, though, and does just what you're asking:

```
/(?<=: ).+/
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @minitech's answer, you can also make a 3rd variation:

```
/(?<=: ?)(.+)/
```

The difference here being, you create/grab the group using a look-behind.

If you still prefer the look-ahead rather than look-behind concept. . .

```
/(?=: ?(.+))/
```

This will place a grouping around your existing regex where it will catch it within a group.

And yes, the outside parenthesis  in your code *will* make a match. Compare that to the latter example I gave where the entire look-ahead is 'grouped' rather than needlessly using a `/( ... )/` without the `/(?= ... )/`, since the first result in most regular expression engines return the entire matched string.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation -- it seems like the first regex has an error though (invalid pattern in look-behind). In any case it seems I'll have to do a lot more learning on grouping / look-behinds.

Comment: Variable-length lookbehinds aren’t allowed, so `/(?<=: ?)(.+)/` won’t work.

Answer (score 1):

I know you are asking for regex but I just saw the regex solution and found that it is rather hard to read for those unfamiliar with regex.

I'm also using Ruby and I decided to do it with:

```
line_as_string.split(": ")[-1]
```

This does what you require and IMHO it's far more readable.
For a very long string it might be inefficient. But not for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, as in PCRE and Boost, you may make use of the `\K` [*match reset operator*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html):

> `\K` keeps the text matched so far out of the overall regex match. `h\Kd` matches only the second `d` in `adhd`.

So, you may use

```
/:[[:blank:]]*\K.+/     # To only match horizontal whitespaces with `[[:blank:]]`
/:\s*\K.+/              # To match any whitespace with `\s`
```

Seee the [Rubular demo #1](https://rubular.com/r/B6kmhQAPwwt1wL) and the [Rubular demo #2](https://rubular.com/r/9VMytb4e2cHoni) and

**Details**

- `:` - a colon
- `[[:blank:]]*` -  0 or more horizontal whitespace chars
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding the text matched so far from the overall match memory buffer
- `.+` - matches and consumes any 1 or more chars other than line break chars (use `/m` modifier to match any chars including line break chars).