# Javascript Regex: match text after pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I have text of a form where there are paragraphs of text with urls interspersed. 
I would like to parse the string creating html links from the urls and using the following text as the descriptive link text i.e.

```
possibly some text here http://www.somewebsite.com/some/path/somepage.html descriptive text which may or may not be present
```

into

```
<a href="http://www.somewebsite.com/some/path/somepage.html">descriptive text which may or may not be present</a>
```

This SO article, [JS: Find URLs in Text, Make Links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625183/js-find-urls-in-text-make-links), is relevant to what I'm attempting to do but simply places the url as the text within the anchor element.

I am successfully matching the url with

```
var urlRE= new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9]+://)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@)?([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?([^ ])+");
```

but am unsure how to perform the match afterwards.

I came across this post [Regex - Matching text AFTER certain characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924274/regex-matching-text-after-certain-characters) which seems applicable. I've attempted to wrap my RE in `/(?<=my url pattern here).+/` but get an error stating that there is an invalid group and that this results in an invalid RE.

In that post  J-Law mentions that

> Variable-length lookbehinds aren’t allowed

Is this what I'm attempting to do?

Since I'm already matching the url I feel like I could easily do some substring math to get the desired results.

I'm just using this as an attempt to learn more about regex.

Thanks

Comment: FYI, not only variable-length lookbehinds are not allowed in most regex flavours *(.NET being the exception to the rule here)*, JavaScript does not support lookbehinds *at all*.

Comment: A note on your regex. It has a requirement there be non-space after the domain. `([^ ])+`.   If there is such a thing as `site.XX`, it won't match. You could change it to `([^ ])*` and I don't think it would matter much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add another capturing group to capture all the stuff at the end and make your inner groups non-capturing. Something like:

```js
    var urlRE= new RegExp("((?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+://)?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@)?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(?::[0-9]+)?(?:[^ ])+)(.*)$");

    var s = "possibly some text here http://www.somewebsite.com/some/path/somepage.html descriptive text which may or may not be present"
    
    var match = urlRE.exec(s);
    alert(match[0] + "\n\n" + match[1] + "\n\n" + match[2]);

    // Returns: 
    // ["http://www.somewebsite.com/some/path/somepage.html descriptive text which may or may not be present", 
    // "http://www.somewebsite.com/some/path/somepage.html", 
    // " descriptive text which may or may not be present"]
```

I wrapped your entire regex in brackets `()` to form the first capturing group and inside that I made all your existing groups non-capturing with `?:`, You don't absolutely need to do that (making them non-capturing), but it does simplify the output. Then I just added one more group `(.*)` to capture everything else until the end of the string `$`.

After `.exec` if you have a match, your match will be in `[0]`, the url part will be in `[1]` and the rest of your text in `[2]`. This is why we used the non-capturing groups because otherwise you'd have a bunch of other captures that may or may not be useful.